# C# GCP auth2.0 403 mismatch redirect

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, identifier

I'm using this code to try to get the auth from Google:

```
 await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Google", new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = "/"});
```

The thing is the redirect always take the HTTP url even if I'm running it from https url.

The url with `https://something-sss.com` is already whitelisted on the GCP API identifiers.

But it always take the Uri with `http`

Comment: can you include a reproducible piece of code? How close is this document[1] to what you are doing? [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: In fact, it's the way you expose your app that is taken in parameters..
For me I'm using the **dockerfile** to expose my app, and I used to use 
`Expose http://*:80`
And even if the associated domain was started with an HTTPS, inside the app it's always an HTTP call, so all the redirect are done through the http protocole.
I'v changed the way I expose my app from http://*:80 to https://*:443
And in the code I used kestrel to launch the app and it's working perfectly now 
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since Stackoverflow is a question and answer site I have taken your comment and posted it as a wiki answer so that it may help others.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with this wiki and stuff .. but I'm happy to help.
Thank you Antonio

Answer (score 1):

To expose my docker app I used to use `Expose http://*:80` and even if the associated domain was started with an HTTPS, inside the app it was always an HTTP call, so all the redirects were done through the http protocol.
I have changed the way I expose my app from `http://*:80` to `https://*:443` in the code I used kestrel to launch the app and it's working perfectly now.